# PL/SQL - Record Type vs Rowtype

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Quando usar um `record type`, definido pelo programador, ao invés de declarar uma variável do tipo `%rowtype`?

ex:

```
/**Definido pelo usuário**/
declare
type bbb is record(
id int,
nome varchar(100));
v bbb;
begin
select id,nome into v.id,v.nome from danilo.teste where id = 10;
dbms_output.put_line(v.nome);
end;
/

/**Utilizando o atributo %rowtype**/
declare
v danilo.teste%rowtype;
begin
select id,nome into v.id,v.nome from danilo.teste where id = 10;
dbms_output.put_line(v.nome);
end;
/
```

Existe algum ganho de performance?

Comment: O rowtype acompanha alguma alteração na tabela ,em geral no casos em que se tratam todos os campos desta , o type se restringe ao que será usado. O ganho é mais de clareza e facilidade de manutenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente `ROWTYPE` está associado a uma tabela física, enquanto `RECORD TYPE` está associado a um objeto.

`%ROWTYPE` deve ser usado sempre que a consulta retornar uma linha inteira de uma tabela ou visualização.

`TYPE rec RECORD` deve ser usado sempre que a consulta retornar colunas de diferentes tabelas ou visualizações e variáveis.

Exemplo:

```
TYPE r_emp IS RECORD (eno emp.empno% type,ename emp ename %type
);
e_rec emp% ROWTYPE
cursor c1 is SELECT empno,deptno FROM emp;
e_rec c1 %ROWTYPE
```

**Desvantagens**

Quando temos uma variável do tipo `RECORD`, temos que declarar variáveis ​​adicionais, mas com `%ROWTYPE`, podemos ter todos os campos que estão presentes na tabela.

**Exemplo de cenário:**

Como `%ROWTYPE` é usado quando você precisa trabalhar com registro completo, e `TYPE RECORD` é usado para criar seu próprio tipo de dados com um número específico de valores a serem retidos. 
Suponha que uma tabela tenha 20 colunas e você precise trabalhar com apenas sete colunas. Se você usar `%ROWTYPE`, você obtém todos os 20 valores desnecessariamente. Ao mesmo tempo, seu programa será um pouco desajeitado se usar sete declarações de `TYPE`. Uma maneira melhor de resolver essa solução é definir meu próprio tipo de dados, que pode conter sete valores.